# Vuforia AR sample App android?

Tags: android, augmented-reality, vuforia

I am following the Vuforia and i have run the samples ,but what if i want to start the our own app so could any one know some Reference  or some book or any thing that can help me to my first start the app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not exactly Vuforia, but I must recommend the following:

Check out Raghav Sood's  book [Pro Android Augmented Reality](http://www.apress.com/9781430239451)
And his [github project](https://github.com/RaghavSood/ProAndroidAugmentedReality)

Comment: so there is nothing for Vuforia

Answer (score 1):

You could integrate vuforia with JPCT-AE. I made a tutorial in its [wiki](http://www.jpct.net/wiki/index.php/Integrating_JPCT-AE_with_Vuforia)

Answer (score -1):

Go for "Developing AR Games for iOS and Android" by Dominic Cushnan. Book for development using Vuforia